Functional derivative
I would like to compute the functional derivative with respect to the marginal Probability Density Function (PDF) $p_X(x)$ and the joint bivariate PDF  $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$. The functional is defined as:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L} = & \; F(p_X(x), p_{X,Y}(x, y)) \\
& + \int \lambda_0(x) \left( p_X(x) - \int p_{X,Y}(x, y) \, dy \right) dx \\
& + \int \lambda_1(y) \left( p_Y(y) - \int p_{X,Y}(x, y) \, dx \right) dy \\
& + \lambda_2 \left( \int p_X(x) \, dx - 1 \right) \\
& + \lambda_3 \left( \int \int p_{X,Y}(x, y) \, dx \, dy - 1 \right) \\
& + \lambda_4 \left( \int x \cdot p_X(x) \, dx - \mu_X \right) \\
& + \lambda_5 \left( \int y \cdot p_Y(y) \, dy - \mu_Y \right),
\end{align*}
where:

$F(p_X(x), p_{X,Y}(x, y))$ depends on both the marginal PDF
$p_X(x)$ and the joint PDF $p_{X,Y}(x, y)$,
$\lambda_0(x)$ and $\lambda_1(y)$ enforce the marginal
constraints,
$\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ enforce the
normalization of $p_X(x)$ and $p_{X,Y}(x, y)$, respectively,
$\lambda_4$ and $\lambda_5$ enforce the average value
constraints with $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ as the target averages.

Taking the functional derivative with respect to $p_X(x)$, we obtain:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta p_X(x)} = & \; \frac{\delta F}{\delta p_X(x)} + \lambda_0(x) + \lambda_2 + \lambda_4 x.
\end{align*}
while taking the functional derivative with respect to $p_{X,Y}(x, y)$, I obtain:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta p_{X,Y}(x, y)} = & \; \frac{\delta F}{\delta p_{X,Y}(x, y)} - \lambda_0(x) - \lambda_1(y) + \lambda_3.
\end{align*}
I have two questions :

Are the calculations correct?

Is there a way to simplify this functional? I mean do I actually have to use 5 Lagrange multipliers or can I for example remove $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_5$ without altering the result? In other words, aren't the constrains imposed on the marginal densities somehow redundant with the one imposed on the joint PDF?


